# What is wrong with my 32u4 breakout board from adafruit?

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I recently bought the atmega 32u4 breakout board from adafruit. I uploaded a sketch, then it says that there isn't a timer 2 on it and it won't do as I programmed my sketch. how can I fix this?

Comment: Please include some more information - especially the code you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to port any libraries and code that depend on timer 2 to the '32U4 architecture. There is no way to add timer 2 to the chip, and it is likely that trying to force it to use a different timer won't help since it may configure things the other timer doesn't have.